# phpexcel not reading sheet correctly

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel, xlsx

I am using phpexcel 1.8 to read a .xlsx file with 92 rows. But I am getting only one row as the result. Then I opened the file & made some edits using libre office & then I tried to save the file & an option came up "Use Microsoft Excel 2007/2010/2013 XML Format" & I clicked on it & saved the file.

Then onwards I am getting correct results from reading the file using phpexcel. What could be wrong ? Any help would be appreciated.

Code I used is:

```
        $inputFileName = 'test.xlsx';
        try {
            $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName);
        } catch (Exception $e) {    
            die('Error loading file "' . pathinfo($inputFileName, PATHINFO_BASENAME) . '": ' . $e->getMessage());
        }

        $highRow = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighestRow();
        $highColumn = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighestColumn();
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think it is some issue with ole recognition. Any help please!

Comment: An xlsx file shouldn't be OLE at all, that's for BIFF-format xls files; an xlsx should be OfficeOpenXML; but it's quite possible that it's something else entirely.... what does `PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);` return?

Comment: @MarkBaker It returns Excel2007.

Comment: Then it's very odd indeed, and must be something unusual in that particular file

Comment: When opening the same file in google sheets and then downloading as .xlsx also works fine with phpexcel.

Comment: OK, so I'll try and guess what it might be and fix it

Comment: OK thanks, the file itself was generated by a program code using dotnet.